# Are there forced factors of numbers of this kind?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

Let $$f(n):=n^{n^2}+(n+1)^{(n+1)^2}$$ for a positive integer $n$. For clarification $n^{n^2}$ means $n^{(n^2)}$ , analogue for the other summand.

> Can we find a concrete factor of $\ f(n)\ $ (like algebraic or aurifeuillan factors) ?

Motivation : I still could not completely factor $f(10)$ (there is a $114$ digit composite left) and I know no factor of the $309$-digit composite number $f(15)$.

See also here : http://factordb.com/index.php?query=n%5E%28n%5E2%29%2B%28n%2B1%29%5E%28%28n%2B1%29%5E2%29

I wonder whether we can use any trick to find the factors easier than by simply using the standard techniques , for example , can we make us of the structure of those numbers if we use the quadratic sieve ?

Comment: The exponents are coprime, and are not independent of the bases, so that's worrying.

Comment: It need not be clarified, it's convention @Peter. Parentheses are only needed, when you want to force a different order, or to group things.

Comment: It's congruent to $n+1$ or $n+2$ mod numbers with Euler phi of 4. Depends on if n is odd, or even respectively.

Comment: If there were nice factors, then probably $f(2)$ wouldn't be prime.

Comment: @Ivan f(1) is also prime. However The Mersenne sequence has a two prime start as well.

Comment: @Roddy Yes, and that's why Mersenne numbers don't have a _general_ factorization. One may argue that they are divisible by 3 for certain $n$'s, and by 5 for certain other $n$'s, and so on. Well, same thing here.

Comment: For prime exponents they do have a specific form of factor however.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think it makes sense to point the order out since many users seem to not know it , as I experienced in other questions.

Comment: Update : $C114$ is finally factored : $P37\cdot P77$ , but I still know no factor of $f(15)$